# Magento Credit Memo Workflow

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, invoice, creditmemo

In a standard Quick books Accounting environment, do Credit Memos generally involve duplicating steps in both Magento and Quick books?

It seems like you need to create the credit memo on Magento and then record the credit memo in Quick books to match the type of refund it was (Refund back to the customer OR Refund credit).

We're using eCC Webgility and I assumed Credit Memos might be a little more streamlined but after some research this issue I'm beginning to think 2 separate steps might be more the norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as being checked by the employee who entered them, credit memo requests need to approved by at least one decision-maker. The value of the credit memo determines who is able to aprove it.

If a credit memo request is created, the system normally creates a billing block. This block prevents you billing the credit memo request and can only be removed by an authorized employee.

Using the workflow, you can represent the whole business process with all the people involved, for approving credit memo requests within your company. This enables you to process credit memo requests simply and efficiently. If you are not using the workflow, you will have to organize the steps in credit memo processing yourself, because the system does not control the process flow.

If, for example, the value of a credit memo request is below a minimum value, the system automatically releases it for billing by removing the billing block.

If the credit memo request exceeds a certain value, the system automatically informs the employee responsible. S/he receives a work item that can be processed directly from the inbox.

The employee responsible can cancel, release, or process a credit memo request.

If the employee cancels the request, the system automatically creates a cancellation reason in the credit memo request and ends processing.

If the employee releases the request, the system automatically removes the billing block in the credit memo request and releases it for billing.

If the employee processes the request, s/he is able to use all the functions available in the change transaction to change it.

Comment: At what point does the customer get there funds returned? It seems like in many cases this is done offline. Does offline mean.. Completing the step in magento and then completing it in the accounting system?